# If, Then statement for Bash Init Script

Tags: bash, function, if-statement

I am trying to get the output of whether a status is running or not via the pid. When I add the following to the script, it only outputs the first echo. Whether or not the process has been killed or not. What am i missing in the first if?

```
  status() {         
          if [  'ps auxww | grep $APPLICATION | grep $SERVICE1 | gawk "{print $2}" | grep -v grep' ]; 
               echo -e $"$SERVICE1 is currently running \n "
          else
               echo -e $"$SERVICE1 is not running \n "
               RETVAL=$?
               echo
          fi
          fi
          return $RETVAL
  }
```

Comment: Second `fi` must be redundant.

Comment: Also, please see [Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).

Answer (score 1):

The `[` is command which is an alias for the "test" command with a required end `]`. The `if` statement in bash tests the exit status of command. In your case, you want to test the exit status of your pipeline, rather than use test.

```
if ps auxww | grep $APPLICATION | grep $SERVICE1 | gawk "{print $2}" | grep -v grep; then
   ...
fi
```

You normally don't want to parse the output of `ps` in this way. Instead, use `pgrep` if available:

```
if pgrep -f "$APPLICATION.*$SERVICE1"; then
   ...
fi
```